# When JSR-308 will become part of JDK?

Tags: java, assert, assertions, design-by-contract, assertion

See [my blog post](http://alexsmail.blogspot.com/2012/06/java-assert-design-by-contract-elvis.html) for excerpt from Java Posse #386 - Newscast for May 31st 2012 that expands this topic.

Does [JSR 308](http://types.cs.washington.edu/jsr308/)  promotes design-by-contract to Java? It is step further from [assertions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html)? When it will be part of JDK?

When it is scheduled to be released as part of JDK?

See also [Do you use assertions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208404/do-you-use-assertions)

Comment: How would we know when it'll be in the JDK? It's "scheduled" for JDK 8 or later. If ever. But no, 308 is an enhancement to *where* annotations can appear. It may *help* in DbC™ implementations, but in itself isn't related. If anywhere, this should be on http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Why programmers? See the addition above.

Comment: It's not a specific question (in addition to the OT parts). I didn't downvote, but I did vote to close as OT.

Comment: I think you're confused on what 308 is. 308 extends **where** annotations can be used. It doesn't have any annotations on its own. As such, it has nothing to do with assertions, DbC™, etc. It may be **used** to implement arbitrary functionality.

Comment: The Checker Framework:Custom pluggable types for Java  Nullness checker
http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checkers-manual.html#nullness-checker

This link I found from JSR 308 page.

Comment: Checker is a tool that uses 308 functionality. To quote from [your link](http://types.cs.washington.edu/jsr308/): "[JSR-308] describes the minor, backward-compatible changes to the Java language and classfile format." It also says "and ***then*** tools such as type-checkers can detect and prevent more errors." Checker is one of those tools. It **uses** 308.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. But for now, neither JSR-308, not type-checkers (that can be expanded for design by contract) is not part of JDK.

Comment: Yes, we're aware of that. Doesn't mean you can't use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSR 308 is not related to contracts. Instead, it extends the Java type system so that you can modify basic types depending on their usage context. The [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/) gives a few great examples of what can be done with type annotations.
I'm sure you can somehow subvert this to turn it into contracts, but you'd still have to add a custom processor that compiles annotations into code rather than just passing them through a type checker.

And currently the plan is to include in the Java 8. But that can still change.

Comment: 'currently the plan is to include in the Java 8. But that can still change.' - thanks for this.